# How can I use dplyr::filter with "|" operator?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I use `dplyr`'s `filter()` function all the time for tidying my data. Today it has stopped working when using the `|` operator. I am certain I have been able to use the `|` to filter any observation that meets any of the criteria separated by the `|` but it isn't working all of a sudden. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated, as always. Reprex is below.

```
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.2
id <- c(1:20)
YEAR <- c(2009,2009,2009,2009,2010,2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013,2013)
df1 <- data.frame(id,YEAR)
df1
#>    id YEAR
#> 1   1 2009
#> 2   2 2009
#> 3   3 2009
#> 4   4 2009
#> 5   5 2010
#> 6   6 2010
#> 7   7 2010
#> 8   8 2010
#> 9   9 2011
#> 10 10 2011
#> 11 11 2011
#> 12 12 2011
#> 13 13 2012
#> 14 14 2012
#> 15 15 2012
#> 16 16 2012
#> 17 17 2013
#> 18 18 2013
#> 19 19 2013
#> 20 20 2013
df1 <- df1 %>% dplyr::filter(YEAR == 2009|2010)
df1
#>    id YEAR
#> 1   1 2009
#> 2   2 2009
#> 3   3 2009
#> 4   4 2009
#> 5   5 2010
#> 6   6 2010
#> 7   7 2010
#> 8   8 2010
#> 9   9 2011
#> 10 10 2011
#> 11 11 2011
#> 12 12 2011
#> 13 13 2012
#> 14 14 2012
#> 15 15 2012
#> 16 16 2012
#> 17 17 2013
#> 18 18 2013
#> 19 19 2013
#> 20 20 2013
```

Expected results would be:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% dplyr::filter(YEAR == 2009|2010)
df1
#>    id YEAR
#> 1   1 2009
#> 2   2 2009
#> 3   3 2009
#> 4   4 2009
#> 5   5 2010
#> 6   6 2010
#> 7   7 2010
#> 8   8 2010
```

The following works filtering on a single condition:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% dplyr::filter(YEAR == 2009)
df1
#>   id YEAR
#> 1  1 2009
#> 2  2 2009
#> 3  3 2009
#> 4  4 2009
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==` for more than one element

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    dplyr::filter(YEAR %in% c(2009, 2010))
```

---

With `|`, we need to repeat

```
df1 %>%
    dplyr::filter(YEAR == 2009|YEAR == 2010)
```

---

Any value greater than 0 with another, gives `TRUE`

```
2019|2020
#[1] TRUE

0|0
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I figured it must have been something simple I'd overlooked. Apologies for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

I think also your way would work with...

```
df1 <- df1 %>% dplyr::filter(YEAR == 2009|YEAR == 2010)
```

I think of it as two separate arguments. If you use each individually, the filter would work.  In your provided `YEAR == 2009|2010`, the second part would simply be `filter(2010)`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I designated akrun's response as the designated answer because it provides two possible solutions. Thank you!